# LWJGL 3 - After the shader is compiled and mesh is made, the triangle still doesn't draw

Tags: java, glsl, rendering, game-engine, lwjgl

I am currently trying to make an engine by using LWJGL3, and I am having issues trying to render a triangle.

I first make the window, make the window current context.
Then I make the renderer, which has the meshes.
Meshes have shaders attached to them. By `init()` the shaders compile and link.
Shader file (I have a parser, which takes fragment/vertex separately. The compilation completes without error, I do have error checking if it fails to compile).

```
#version 330
layout (location=0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location=1) in vec4 aColor;

out vec4 fragment;

void main(){
    fragment = aColor;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos,1.0);
}
//type fragment
#version 330

in vec4 fColor;

out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = fColor;
}
```

After this, I try to draw the mesh, it succeeds so, but in the window, I only get a gray color, which is a color I passed as an argument to start the window by that color.

Where could I be going wrong?

Mesh code:

```
package graphics;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL33.*;

public class Mesh {
    int positionSize = 3;
    int colorSize = 4;
    int floatSizeInBytes = 4;
    int vertexSizeInBytes = (positionSize + colorSize) * floatSizeInBytes;

    private final Vertex[] vertices;
    private final int[] indices;

    private int vertexArrayObject;
    private int vertexBufferObject;
    private int elementArrayObject;
    private int vertexCount;
    private Shader shader;

    public Mesh(Vertex[] vertices, int[] indices, Shader shader) {
        this.shader = shader;
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.indices = indices;
    }

    public void init(){
        this.shader.compileAndLink();
        this.shader.bind();

        vertexCount = indices.length;

        vertexArrayObject = glGenVertexArrays();
        vertexBufferObject = glGenBuffers();
        elementArrayObject = glGenBuffers();

        glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, flippedBuffer(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementArrayObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, flippedBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, positionSize, GL_FLOAT, false, vertexSizeInBytes, 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, colorSize, GL_FLOAT, false, vertexSizeInBytes, (long) positionSize * floatSizeInBytes);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void render() {
        bind();

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        unbind();
        System.out.println("Rendered");
    }

    public void clear() {
        glDeleteBuffers(vertexBufferObject);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vertexArrayObject);

        shader.unbind();
    }

    public void bind() {
        glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementArrayObject);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void stop() {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        shader.unbind();
    }

    public void setShader(Shader shader) {
        try {
            stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Shader could not be stopped or not running");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.shader = shader;
        this.shader.bind();
    }

    public int getVertexArrayObject() {
        return vertexArrayObject;
    }

    public int getVertexBufferObject() {
        return vertexBufferObject;
    }

    public int getVertexCount() {
        return vertexCount;
    }

    public int getElementArrayObject() {
        return elementArrayObject;
    }

    public FloatBuffer flippedBuffer(Vertex[] vertices) {
        FloatBuffer buffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(vertices.length * 7);
        for (Vertex vertex : vertices) {
            buffer.put(vertex.getPosition().coordinateArray());
            buffer.put(vertex.getColor().coordinateArray());
        }
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

    public IntBuffer flippedBuffer(int[] elements) {
        IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(elements.length);
        for (int element : elements) {
            buffer.put(element);
        }
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Shader code:

```
package graphics;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL33.*;

public class Shader {

    private int shaderProgrammeID;

    private String vertexSource;
    private String fragmentSource;
    private final String filePath;

    public Shader(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        try {
            String source = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
            String[] splitString = source.split("(//type)( )+([a-zA-Z]+)");

            int index = source.indexOf("//type") + 6;
            int endOfLine = source.indexOf("\r\n", index);
            String firstPattern = source.substring(index, endOfLine).trim();

            index = source.indexOf("//type", endOfLine) + 6;
            endOfLine = source.indexOf("\r\n", index);
            String secondPattern = source.substring(index, endOfLine).trim();

            if (firstPattern.equals("vertex")) {
                vertexSource = splitString[1];
            } else if (firstPattern.equals("fragment")) {
                fragmentSource = splitString[1];
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected shader type " + firstPattern + "'");
            }

            if (secondPattern.equals("vertex")) {
                vertexSource = splitString[2];
            } else if (secondPattern.equals("fragment")) {
                fragmentSource = splitString[2];
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected shader type " + secondPattern + "'");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            assert false : "Error: Could not Open Shader" + filePath + "'";
        }
    }

    public void compileAndLink() {
        int vertexID;
        int fragmentID;

        vertexID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexID, vertexSource);
        glCompileShader(vertexID);

        if (glGetShaderi(vertexID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: vertex shader - " + filePath + "could not be be compiled");
            System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexID, glGetShaderi(vertexID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));
            assert false : "";
        }

        fragmentID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentID, fragmentSource);
        glCompileShader(fragmentID);

        if (glGetShaderi(fragmentID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: fragment shader - " + filePath + "could not be be compiled");
            System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentID, glGetShaderi(fragmentID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));
            assert false : "";
        }

        this.shaderProgrammeID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(this.shaderProgrammeID, vertexID);
        glAttachShader(this.shaderProgrammeID, fragmentID);
        glLinkProgram(this.shaderProgrammeID);

        if (glGetProgrami(this.shaderProgrammeID, GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + filePath + " shaders could not be linked");
            System.out.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(this.shaderProgrammeID, glGetProgrami(fragmentID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));
            assert false : "";
        }
        System.out.println("Shader " + filePath + " compiled and linked successfully");
    }

    public void bind() {
        glUseProgram(shaderProgrammeID);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        glUseProgram(0);
    }
}
```

Here is the renderer object, I use this to encapsulate Meshes to render them.

```
package graphics;

import java.util.HashSet;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL33.*;

public class Renderer {

    private final HashSet<Mesh> meshes;

    public Renderer() {
        meshes = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void init() {
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glFrontFace(GL_CW);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        for (Mesh mesh : meshes) {
            mesh.init();
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        clear();
        for (Mesh mesh : meshes) {
            mesh.render();
        }
    }

    public void addMesh(Mesh mesh) {
        meshes.add(mesh);
    }

    public void removeMesh(Mesh mesh) {
        meshes.remove(mesh);
    }

    public void clear() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        for (Mesh mesh : meshes) {
            mesh.unbind();
            mesh.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Engine code:

```
package core;

import graphics.Mesh;
import graphics.Renderer;
import io.Input;
import math.Vector4f;
import utils.Time;

public class Engine implements Runnable {


    public static final int TARGET_FPS = 30;

    private final Thread thread;
    private final MainBehaviour behaviour;
    private final Window window;


    public Engine(Window window, MainBehaviour mainBehaviour) {
        this.thread = new Thread(this, "loop");
        this.window = window;
        this.behaviour = mainBehaviour;
    }

    public void init() throws Exception {
        Time.init(TARGET_FPS);
        window.init();
        behaviour.init();
    }

    public void start() {
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            init();
            loop();
            clear();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        behaviour.clear();
        window.destroy();
    }

    private void update() {
        behaviour.update();

        /*Updating Time */
        Time.updateFps();
        Time.updateCycle();

        /* Input handling */
        Input.update();
        window.update();
    }

    private void render() {
        behaviour.render(window);
    }

    public void loop() {
        while (window.isRunning()) {

            /* Updating delta Time for correct interval Calculation */
            Time.updateDeltaTime();

            /* Rendering and actually updating Game */
            while (Time.checkCycle()) {
                update();
            }

            render();

            System.out.println(Time.getFps());

            if (!window.isVSync()) {
                Time.sync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Window code:

```
package core;

import graphics.Renderer;
import io.Input;
import math.Vector4f;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.glfwFreeCallbacks;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;


public class Window {
    private final Vector4f color;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private long window;
    private long monitor;
    private boolean isFullScreen;
    private boolean isVSync;
    private String name;
    private GLFWVidMode mode;
    private final Renderer renderer;


    public Window(int width, int height, String name, Vector4f color, boolean isVSync, Renderer renderer) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.isVSync = isVSync;
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    public Window(int width, int height, String name, String monitor, Vector4f color, Renderer renderer) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        if (monitor.equals("primary")) {
            this.monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
            mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        }
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    public Renderer getRenderer() {
        return renderer;
    }

    public boolean isVSync() {
        return isVSync;
    }

    public void setVSync(boolean vSync) {
        this.isVSync = vSync;
    }

    public boolean isFullScreen() {
        return isFullScreen;
    }

    public void setFullScreen(boolean fullScreen) {
        isFullScreen = fullScreen;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void init() {
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("GLFW not initialized or initialization failed");
        } else {
            GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
            try {
                if (monitor != NULL) {
                    this.monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
                    mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
                    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, name, glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
                    isFullScreen = true;
                } else {
                    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, name, NULL, NULL);
                }
                if (window == NULL) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(this.window);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        Input.init();
        setupCallback();

        renderer.init();
    }

    private void setupCallback() {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, Input.getKeyboard());
        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, Input.getMbtn());
        glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, Input.getMouse());
    }

    public void destroy() {
        renderer.destroy();
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    public void setWindowed(int width, int height, int x, int y) {
        glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, NULL, x, y, width, height, mode.refreshRate());
    }

    public void fullScreenWindow() {
        glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, NULL, 0, 0, mode.width(), mode.height(), mode.refreshRate());
    }

    public void fullScreen() {
        glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, monitor, 0, 0, mode.width(), mode.height(), 0);
    }

    public void update() {
        if (!isRunning()) {
            destroy();
            return;
        }

        renderer.render();

        clear();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    public void clear() {
        glClearColor(color.x, color.y, color.z, color.w);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return !glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
    }

}
```

I render in `update()`

And the main class where I call the whole thing to run:

```
import core.Engine;
import core.MainBehaviour;
import core.Window;
import graphics.Mesh;
import graphics.Renderer;
import graphics.Shader;
import graphics.Vertex;
import io.Input;
import math.Vector3f;
import math.Vector4f;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_KEY_SPACE;

public class Preview {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                MainBehaviour game = new MainBehaviour() {
            @Override
            public void init() throws Exception {

            }

            @Override
            public void update() {
                if (Input.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_SPACE))
                    System.out.println("Space button pushed");
            }

            @Override
            public void render(Window window) {

            }

            @Override
            public void clear() {

            }
        };

        Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[]{
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(-1f, -1f, 0f), new Vector4f(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)),
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(0f, 1f, 0f), new Vector4f(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f)),
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(1f, -1f, 0f), new Vector4f(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f)),
        };
        int[] indices = new int[]{
                0, 1, 2
        };
        Shader shader = new Shader("res/shaders/default.glsl");
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh(vertices, indices, shader);
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer();
        renderer.addMesh(mesh);
        Window window = new Window(500, 500, "Preview", new Vector4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f), false, renderer);
        Engine engine = new Engine(window, game);
        engine.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to render from a thread? The [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is thread-local.

Comment: Oh yes thats true. So If I pass the window ID(the long) to the renderer, and just before rendering I `glMakeCurrentContext` it may work? Do you suggest this?

Comment: I do not know. Way too much code. Narrow it down to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Always keep in mind that the order of vertices for a mesh is important. There is only one front visible unless you turn on front and back face culling. If the mesh you created is correct and the setup is fine in principle (camera looking at the mesh) changing 0, 1, 2 to 0, 2, 1 could do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The vertex shader color output name is `fragment`, but the fragment shader input name is `fColor`. The interface is linked by name. You must use the same name on both sides of the interface. Change the vertex shader:

```c
#version 330
layout (location=0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location=1) in vec4 aColor;

out vec4 fColor;

void main(){
    fColor = aColor;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Corrected as said, still, it only shows gray screen... But about the linkage, I didn't know. I'll mind that for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be clearing the buffer right after rendering the triangle and before swapping the buffer's contents to screen.

In your window code:

```
...
renderer.render();

clear();
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
...
```

You clear the buffer's contents right before swapping it to the window instead of clearing before rendering:

```
...
clear();

renderer.render();

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
...
```

Comment: Made the suggested changes, but still the same kind of output.